# Android install app B from app A and send sensitive data to it

Tags: android, kotlin

I know title does not explain a lot, but I found it hard to put situation in 1 sentence.

Anyways, we have App A and App B, both android apps. In our App A we have functionality that allows us to open app B with deeplink (it opens particular screen in app B and logs in the user with token). This feature works fine when App B is already installed (in app A we have option to install app B).

But we have problem in situation where App B is not installed. In this case when user clicks in app A to open deeplink in app B, we send user to process of installation of app B. Problem here is that we don't know where to save deeplink and token while we do installation process (we are outside of app A and we don't communicate with it anymore).

One idea is to save this to clipboard, but it is pretty unsafe to do this with tokens.

Any better ideas how to solve this. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Comment: @Eric you mean Install app B from app A and than app B at the cold start checks if the content provider in app A is available and it would get deeplink and token from it?

Comment: If yes, this is problematic solution for us because we are owners of app A and can develop changes here. App B is not under our control and we are unable to make development here on our own...

Comment: You can save it in EncryptedSharedPreferences, but you'll be able to check if there is some data in these preferences only if user will resume app A. In App A Activity's onResume you can check if there is some deeplink in EncryptedSharedPreferences and try to proceed to App B again. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/security/crypto/EncryptedSharedPreferences

Comment: @MikhailGuliaev but we can not resume app A. After we enter the installation process of app B, we don't come back to app A. We just proceed to app B. That is the main problem, we can not use data storage of app A

Comment: Yes, as I said it will work only if user will resume app A. If he will not, you may encounter some problems with starting another app from background due to Android restrictions: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts. Otherwise you could display notification which will open app B, but I am not sure that this is valid solution since you will not be able to control if app B is already installed or not.

Comment: Yeah both of ideas do not work in this situation